Running QuantConnect LEAN code fully locally
I've been trying to figure out how to run a trading algorithm fully locally without any connection to QuantConnect's resources. We have a custom feed and the algorithm just need to create signals. So no brokerage connection is needed.
I got so far that I have the LEAN CLI installed and can start up the code locally with:
lean live deploy "$PJT" --brokerage "Paper Trading" --data-provider-live "Custom data only" 

It starts up fine but then stops with the following error:
20241205 18:16:26.111 ERROR:: LiveTradingDataFeed.CreateSubscription(): CreateSubscription(): Failed configuration:                         
'SPY,#0,SPY,Minute,TradeBar,Trade,Adjusted,OpenInterest,Internal' System.NotImplementedException: QuantConnect.Queues.LiveDataQueue has not 
implemented live data. 

I Google'd the hell out of this and found no explanation or solution to this. I don't know how the "SPY" gets in there. There's no reference to it in the trading algorithm.
I'm looking for any data that shed some light on this and can lead to a solution.
